# In double slit experiments of particles (quantum) which the result is interference pattern, How many particles reach the observing screen?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment, interference, statistics

I mean, I know the particles that reach the screen are going both/neither/either of slits and interference with themselves but statically/percentage how many particles interact with slits, are there any particles that reflected from slit partition?

Comment: Are you asking how many particles are absorbed/reflected by the material into which the slits are cut? That depends on the exact experimental setup, and why would that be an interesting question, anyway?

Comment: Particles aren't interacting with the slit, at all. It's a (as in ONE) quantum field that does. "Particles" in that experiment are merely the physical expression of the quantization condition of that field. It can only change its state in discrete quanta, hence we can only measure these discrete changes which some people still call particles, even though they should know better.

Comment: Yes, I'm asking how many particles are absorbed/reflected, I never saw an information about that. And it occured to me if there is an interference pattern(when particle act as a wave) will it always find its way through slits or some will just reflect as particles do. Not asking for exact statistics but is there %100 or %0 or between them.

Comment: No material is perfectly absorptive and it doesn't matter, either. Up to a couple of phase terms you would probably get a very similar looking interference pattern if you made the entire slit out of perfectly reflecting mirrors. The experiment is not sensitive to these things, at all. That also makes it completely useless for anything else other than as a student confusion device and that's really all it has ever been in physics proper.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure I will get interference pattern. Waves do reflect but will particle-waves reflect too? When a water wave reach double slit in some of it reflects some of it go in slits but an electron wave can't divide into 2 things so when it reflect whole electron is reflected, I wonder if an electron wave will ever reflect? If you don't know the answer it's okay probably 99.9% people don't just don't comment about my curiosity or the quality of the question!

Comment: Charged particles can be reflected with an electrostatic potential... not a problem, still a total waste of time to even contemplate these experiments. Physics is only interested in precision experiments where all the variables can be controlled to a great extent. This is not the kind of interferometer that would allow for the necessary error control.

Comment: @ACuriousMind, ..."and why would that be an interesting question, anyway?" As a side note, don't forget that people often come here not only to ask "interesting questions." Sometimes a person may be trying to work out something and a particular question arises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know the particles that reach the screen are going both/neither/either of slits

The wave includes configurations that go through one slit and configurations that goes through the other. But we don't know if a particle went though both or either or just didn't exist when we weren't looking. There is no reason to think they stop existing when we aren't looking, but by definition we wouldn't know, so there isn't anything to worry about if they have to act weird while we don't look. And there are other situations, such as entangled states or different spin components where even thinking the particle has a well defined result before the measurement will actually lead to problems. So it can be good practice to not think it has to have a position when you aren't looking.

> and interference with themselves

And it is the wave that interferes. You can do the experiment so slowly that there is almost zero chance that two particles are in flight at the same time.

> but statically/percentage how many particles interact with slits

The classic experiment has the electrons not interact with the slit. You could even split a beam and then turn each beam to head towards the same screen. As long as the spreading of the beams allows them to overlap before they reach the screen then you are fine.

> are there any particles that reflected from slit partition?

There could be, those particles are wasted. It just means you fire more at the slits than arrive. The ones that arrive are the ones that make the interference pattern.

And the pattern itself is strips of regions that get more particles to land and ones that get relatively fewer.

You can make also diffraction grating where 100% of the particles make it through. This is not the first diffraction experiment that comes up because it is not the simplest, but it does show that the turning away is not important.

An example is a phase diffraction grating. Imagine you had some totally transparent glass and you etched a series of lines into it. All the light goes through but the amount of phase it gets when it goes through an etched part is larger because it gets to go through more vacuum and less glass.

The point is that you just want to have different phases for different paths to get interference. With one giant slit the different phases just line up to not have alternating regions of higher and lower intensity